# Running Prometheus on Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, prometheus

I have set up prometheus to run on Lambda to scrape node level metrics from all EC2's within an AWS account using auto discovery. However, as prometheus is a daemon it kind of abruptly stop/times out when the lambda times out.

My question - Is there a way I can have prometheus just scrape the metrics only once per node and graciously stop within a lambda ?

Comment: Rather than pull metrics, are there options with Prometheus to push metrics from the individual EC2 instances? Note also that CloudWatch metrics collects a lot of metrics about EC2, so some of this is already available to you.

Comment: 2 Issues with above approach    1) Need to install prom on each ec2   2) cloudwatch metrics doesnt have lot of agent level metrics/ has only basic metrics on cloudwqtch

Comment: What's the issue with installing a Prometheus agent on your EC2 instances?

Comment: Talking about enterprise solution here,... prometheus on every ec2 might be very cpu/memory intensive. If lambda can scrape node metrics every 2 mins from ec2 think it will be very optimal and easy to manage